# How Can I store attributes to add_cart Manually in Zen Cart?

Tags: database, cart, zen-cart, zen

1. It's Default Store in Zen Cart > http://awesomescreenshot.com/00bcd2jdf so I just want  to add this manually attribute by my customized page >  http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ebcd1w57

How can I store it and Which table in Zen cart? In this site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to define the option and its possible values in the products_options and products_options_values tables, and then attach the possible combinations to products in the products_attributes table, otherwise they're not going to be handled properly by the order process.

When placing an affected product in the shopping cart you would need to pass information about the options and values for the item being purchased in the form's post array.

However, this is an awful lot of work just to do stuff that's already built into Zen Cart.